# Bootstrap customizing responsive design

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Let's say I have 3 div columns (`span4` each) in a row and the last column gets hidden when the screen is reduced below tablet size. When this happens, I want to replace the other 2 columns' div class with `span6` so I don't see any empty space from hiding.

I am trying to control this from jQuery but I seem to miss out something.

```
$(function() {

  var $resizable = $('.resize');

  if($('.box') === prop(':hidden')) {
    $resizable.toggleClass('span6');
  }

}(jQuery));
```

Here is the [JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/iXuB/3/edit)

Comment: Have you checked Bootstrap 3? the new grid system makes it easy to customize the width of the spans at the different screen sizes

Comment: @koala_dev Thanks for your input. I checked the new version briefly but since I need to use the template I bought which does not support the latest, I need to stick with the older version!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not exactly what you asked for, but you could use media queries to adjust column width.

like this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { /* phone */
  .row-fluid .custom-column {
    /* values from .span6 */
    width:48.717948717948715% !important;
    *width:48.664757228587014% !important;
  }
}
```

as for javascript, try this:

```
var $resizable = $('.resize');

if(!$('.box').is(":visible")) {
  $resizable.removeClass('span4').addClass('span6');
} else {
  $resizable.removeClass('span6').addClass('span4');
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! span4 gets replaced with span6 now but span6 seems to be set by default and so it pushes the last column to the next row. http://jsbin.com/iXuB/6/edit

Comment: what window width is at the start? your last div is .hidden-tablet.hidden-phone , so it's visible only when width is > 979px

Comment: As far as I understand, its state should revert back to visible automatically when not in tablet or phone size. Do you mean I should explicitly make the 3rd column visible like visible-desktop for jQuery to detect it?

Comment: currently that code is executed once. for .span4/.span6 state to revert back, you should hook the code on 'resize' event:

`$(document).resize(do_spans);`

Comment: would you care to demonstrate this?

Comment: Thanks. I still see the red column pushed down to the next row. I'm trying to get all columns sit in one row when the screen size is larger than tablet.

Comment: then you have to use media queries, because resize event is not triggered often enough. see: http://jsbin.com/IYECOZO/5/edit , it seems to do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript show an error on firebug console:

ReferenceError: prop is not defined

if($('.box') === prop(':hidden')) {

To check if something is not visible use .is(":visible"))
in your code is something like this:

```
$(function() {

  var $resizable = $('.resize');

  if(!$('.box').is(":visible")) {
    $resizable.toggleClass('span6');
  }

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried with your code as it seems to make much better sense but it still doesn't give me the output I am looking for. http://jsbin.com/iXuB/5/edit

Comment: I dont understand what you want to achive? can you explain it with an image of how do you want it to be??